# Here's one way to trigger an animation update event in matplotlib - but only works on OS X. Looking for fix on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a case of working code on OS X and non-working code on Ubuntu 16.04. The sequence of stopping and starting the animation timer in matplotlib repaints the screen immediately on OS X (which is what I want) but on Ubuntu the re-enabled timer waits until it fires for the first time - one full interval after it's been re-enabled. Anyone have any clue how to trigger an animation repaint?

Here's a full minium working sample - stopping and starting the timer at the end of the key_handler event does the trick on OS X. But not on Ubuntu.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time, os, sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
colorindex = 0

def key_handler(event):
  global colors
  global colorindex
  global ani
  print('Key pressed:', event.key)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  if event.key == 'x':
    print "Exiting..."
    sys.exit(0)
  elif event.key == 'c':
    print "changing color"
    colorindex += 1
    if colorindex >= len(colors):
      colorindex = 0
  ani.event_source.stop()
  ani.event_source.start()

def animate(i):
  global colors
  global colorindex
  ax1.clear()
  someX = range(1,1000)
  someY = []
  for i in someX:
    someY.append(random.randrange(0, 1000))
  ax1.plot(someX, someY, '.', color=colors[colorindex], markersize=8, label="Some Values")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_handler)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.rcParams['keymap.quit'] = 'x'  # redefine 'x' as the exit key as we're using q for the quotient spectrum
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=5000)
plt.show()
```